# Lazyload polyfill / Magneto 2 js error "loading-attribute-polyfill.js Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined"

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lazy-loading, magento2, polyfills

**I am trying to load [this lazyload polyfill script](https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill) into my Magneto 2 project.**

**The code works but there is a console error I am trying to fix and having no luck.**

Chrome console:
loading-attribute-polyfill.js Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
at loading-attribute-polyfill.js:263

Safari console:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module

**I have tried loading it in the head via xml, manually before end in a phtml template, and also through requirejs-config.js, all give the same error.**

In case it matters I was loading it via requirejs like this:

```
var config = {
    deps: [
      "js/vendor/loading-attribute-polyfill"
    ],
    map: { ... } 
};
```

Has anyone implemented this script into magento 2 without this error? Is there a manual edit I can make to the script to workaround this?

Cheers!!

[image]

Comment: Which version of this polyfil are you trying to use? There are many versions https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill/tree/master/dist
The UMD one looks to be RequireJS compatible

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I am using the 'normal' version (this is the only one that actually works). I did try the UMD one but this breaks the functionality (images do not get moved out of their 'noscript' wrappers), and I get a "Mismatched anonymous define() module:". I tried loading it in via requirejs, using 'deps' in requirejs-config.js, and also the other ways mentioned above. The 'module' version gives a "Unexpected token 'export'" error. From what I can tell the script seems to work completely fine apart from this console error, but I still need to stop it happening!

Comment: @DamianDziaduch if you put that in an answer you can have the bounty (I can't award a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of this polyfil are you trying to use? There are many versions https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill/tree/master/dist

The UMD one looks to be RequireJS compatible, but will probably need changes in the config.

Answer (score 0):

@DamianDziaduch after replying to your comment I tried using the UMD version again via requireconfig.js 'deps' and it does work, console error gone, must have been caching or something when I tried before ‍♀️ thanks for the tip!
Now I know to use UMD javascript where possible in magento2/requirejs (I did not come across this info when Googling!)

Comment: I am going to add the answer so you can give me the bounty :)